# Child window is not closed when parent window is refreshed

Tags: javascript

In my application there is one tab start new application in which 4 links come. when I click on any link a child window opens. Suppose I opened 2 child windows from that links. Now I click again on start new application and then open other 3 child windows from links. now when I logoff only the parent window and the 3 child windows opened at last are closed and the 2 child windows opened earlier are not closed. I want them to close

My code from where child window is opening is 
             if(rowData.productVersion == "1001"){

```
                        childWindow[childWindow.length]=is1001Opened=window.open('/eApps/layout/multipleAppPage.jsp?windowID='+windowID+'&newTitle='+rowData.productCode+'&paramTemp='+uri_encode); 
                    }else{

                        childWindow[childWindow.length]=window.open('/eApps/layout/multipleAppPage.jsp?windowID='+windowID+'&newTitle='+rowData.productCode+'&paramTemp='+uri_encode); 
                    }
```

And my logout code is

```
{
    $('#'+id).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#centerContent').load('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/'+target);
    });
} else {
    $('#'+id).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var r=confirm("logout");
        if (r==true) {
            for (var i=0;i<childWindow.length;i++) {
                if (childWindow[i] && !childWindow[i].closed) 
                    childWindow[i].close();
            }
            window.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited your code but there is no `if` condition (at the beginning of your code) : could you please add it? And if would be nice if you comment your code (just a little but it is easier to understand when you explain in the code, in particular where does the variable `childWindow` comes from)...

Comment: `But if I move to some other link in parent window`, what *exactly* do you mean by this? Do you mean loading another page with another URL? If so, then of course you can't close the window opened by the first page, the second page doesn't know about it.

Comment: In my application there is one tab start new application in which 4 links come. when I click on any link a child window opens. Suppose I opened 2 child windows from that links. Now I click again on start new application and then open other 3 child windows from links. now when I logoff only the parent window and the 3 child windows opened at last are closed and the 2 child windows opened earlier are not closed. I want them to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

earlier I declared the variable as

```
                 var childWindow= new Array();
```

Now I have made the variable static

```
            var childWindow;
            if (typeof childWindow!="object")
            childWindow= new Array();
```